# p:inputText blur event doesn't work the first time

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have the code below with java, JSF, and PrimeFaces, but when I start for the first time the program, the event Blur doesn't work, just after the first time, it worked. Could you know why this works like that?

The main problem here is, the event blur should work the first time.

```html
<p:column headerText="Col1">
      <p:inputText style="width:100px;" id="valorUnitario"
             disabled="#{OrcamentoNovoBean.desabilitar}"
             value="#{item.valor}" converter="BigDecimalConverter"
             onkeypress="javascript:return currencyFormat(this,'.',',',event,2);"
             onkeydown="javascript:return pressTabSaldo(event, #{indiceVar});"
             maxlength="12">
             <p:ajax 
                listener="#{OrcamentoNovoBean.verificaCalculoPecasMaoDeObraSaldo()}"
                event="blur"
update=":form1:dataTablePecas:valorTotalSaldo,:form1:totalSaldo,:form1:totalEstoque,:form1:btnEnviar" />
     </p:inputText>
</p:column>
```

Comment: Can you try adding a delay in your onkey ... functions?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the `blur` event. There is no need to check or update things if the value has not changed. It is just a waste of resources. It's better to just use the default `change` event. As it is the default, you can simply remove the `event` attribute from `p:ajax`.

I also noticed you are using an `onkeypress` listener to format the value as a currency. If you would use [`p:inputNumber`](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inputNumber.xhtml), you'll get currency formatting out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Just to update this. I resolved including onblur="function" I dont know why this works like that, but at the first time Java pickup the event blur inside the inputtext, at second time AJAX works